# PHP OOP Session Object - Serialize UnSerialize - Dealing With it

Tags: php

I'm build some common class objects that will be tucked in the $_SESSION object routinely.  I learned that while adding an object to a session sometimes it can be added without serialize but it is unreliable so i serialize first and it works everytime.

I find the following to be incredibly tedius/repetive and clunky... its like i have to check out the object from the session do some work and then remember to check it in the right way.  Is there a better/more creative way that is also efficient and re-useable.  help php experts

```
// Painful Code
$tmpObj = new clsSession;  // Class setup for intellisense to work.
$tmpObj = unserialize($_SESSION['objSession']);  // I assign so i can get intellisense as well.  
$tmpObj //... do some work make some changes some other logic could be lengthy... 
// and then i have to remember to do the following
$_SESSION['objSession'] = serialize($tmpObj);
unset $tmpObj;

/* or better */

$tmpObj = $_SESSION['objSession'];
$tmpObj = unserialize($tmpObj);
$tmpObj //... do some work make some changes some other logic
//and then i have to remember to do the following
$_SESSION['objSession'] = serialize($tmpObj);
unset $tmpObj;
```

Comment: Why do you serialize it before you store it in session?

Comment: The session handler should take care of any serialization that is needed to store the `$_SESSION` array.

Comment: i found with objects that the session objects frequently fail to carry across pages  many times if it isn't serialized and i saw this problem posted on various articles/web pages about needing to serialize first before assigning.   I wish i didn't but without out the session object frequently nulls out when trying to re-use it after.   PHP 5.3 apache 2.2

Comment: @TimWiley It's an interesting issue. Can you include links to those articles?

Comment: @ Mathieu  - Here is just one right here in stack - look for title "storing objects in php session"  this is the exact problem i had... and there are others with the same issue outside of stack as well.

Comment: If you don't trust the default session handler, you can always [write your own](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php).

Comment: As others have said, the session itself ought to deal with serialisation. If you have issues with that, PHP has [a mechanism for setting up your own session handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php). There are some objects (eg PHP's SOAPClient) that just cannot be serialised. You can't get around that for those specific classes, but for the most part you shouldn't have any issues. The only thing I would say is that it would be good to minimise the amount of objects in the session, because serialising/deserialising a lot of objects will slow things down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tim, Thank you for your input. Years ago I experienced stability problems with objects and sessions; serialized and non-serialized. Missing class definitions during session deserialization are common. If a class definitions undefined, PHP creates incomplete objects of the class __PHP_Incomplete_Class. This degenerated object misses every method. To avoid this error, every class definition must be included before starting the session. So if you implement your auto-loader prior to starting a session you will not have any issues. This solution has worked well for the last 6+ years.

Answer (score 0):

In the object which is being serialized use a `__sleep` magic method. This simply returns an array of the properties which are required between requests and allows the auto-serialise objects in SESSION to work correctly.

e.g.

```
public function __sleep() {
    return array('these', 'are', 'property', 'identifiers');
}
```

Comment: Can't the _sleep method set the session itself?

Comment: This would then couple the object to SESSION, coupling is bad, mmkay.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the object directly into the session without serializing it first. This is because serialization takes place automatically when the session is saved. Just make sure you are autoloading the class definition. If not, you will have to include the class definition on every page that you wish to use the stored session object.

Comment: Joe i found through painful troubleshooting stability problems with assigning the object to the class without serialize.  I found it works until you cross web pages and then frequently the object in the session is nulled across pages... I researched this and found that many people ran into this and had to force a serialize on their object and it stopped it from happening.  This worked for me.

Comment: Tim, Thank you for your input. I also experienced stability problems with objects and sessions; serialized and non-serialized. Especially missing class definitions during session deserialization are a common error. If a class definitions is not defined, PHP creates incomplete objects of the class __PHP_Incomplete_Class. This degenerated object misses every method. To avoid this error, every class definition must be included before starting the session.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, all you are doing is serializing twice:

```
<?php

class Foo{
    public $id;
}

$f = new Foo;
$f->id = 33;

var_dump( serialize($f) ); // Standard storage
var_dump( serialize(serialize($f)) ); // Yours
```

The only difference I can spot is that standard *automagical* unserialize happens on session load (on `session_start()`) which often happens at an early stage and it's possible that you still haven't loaded the class definition. With your code, session is read first and object is recomposed when you call `unserialize()` manually.

I suggest you review your `include_once()` directives and make sure all the required class definitions are loaded before session_start() happens.

Here's a very forced test case:

```
<?php

session_start();
if( empty($_SESSION) ){
    require_once('./foo.php');

    $f = new Foo;
    $f->id = 33;

    $_SESSION['f'] = $f;
    // object(Foo)#1 (1) { ["id"]=> int(33) } 
}else{
    $f = $_SESSION['f'];
    // object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#1 (2) { ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=> string(3) "Foo" ["id"]=> int(33) } 
}
var_dump($f);
```